# How can I return rows for IDs that meet criteria for EXACTLY 3 occurrences in a row?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a requirement that is throwing me for a loop.**I have to return location IDs that have *exactly* 3 consecutive rows of monthly invoice amounts >$2,000. In other words, I do not want to return IDs for mature locations (that might have hundreds of monthly invoices rows).**

**Rextester example data: http://rextester.com/CNJC15871**

**Info:**

- The report will be run on the first of each month
- Monthly invoice dates are the 15th of the month

**Desired Output:** In the invoice table below,

- For a report run date of 10/1, loc_ids 2223 and 3344 would be returned, because 9/15 was the third ever consecutive month of invoice amount >$2,000
- For a report run date of 11/1, loc_id 6678 would be returned, by the same logic.
- For subsequent report months, 2223, 3344, and 6678 should **NOT** be returned because they have >3 consecutive months >$2,000.

  ```
  | loc_id | invoice_date | invoice_amt | Notes                     |
  |--------|--------------|-------------|---------------------------|
  | 1234   | 5/15/2002    | 7000        |                           |
  | 1234   | 6/15/2002    | 8000        |                           |
  | ..     | …            | …           |                           |
  | 1234   | 11/15/2017   | 58000       |                           |
  |        |              |             |                           |
  | 9987   | 11/15/2006   | 7500        |                           |
  | 9987   | 12/15/2006   | 8500        |                           |
  | …      | …            |             |                           |
  | 9987   | 11/15/2017   | 63000       |                           |
  |        |              |             |                           |
  | 5544   | 3/15/2015    | 9200        |                           |
  | 5544   | 4/15/2015    | 10000       |                           |
  | …      | …            |             |                           |
  | 5544   | 11/15/2017   | 70000       |                           |
  |        |              |             |                           |
  | 2223   | 5/15/2017    | 2500        | Count| >2000              |
  | 2223   | 6/15/2017    | 1375        | Do not count| <2000       |
  | 2223   | 7/15/2017    | 8000        | Restart count| >2000 (1)  |
  | 2223   | 8/15/2017    | 9000        | Continue count| >2000 (2) |
  | 2223   | 9/15/2017    | 9800        | Continue count| >2000 (3) |
  | 2223   | 10/15/2017   | 10500       | Stop count| >3 in a row   |
  | 2223   | 11/15/2017   | 11200       | Stop count| >3 in a row   |
  |        |              |             |                           |
  | 3344   | 7/15/2017    | 3500        | Count| >2000 (1)          |
  | 3344   | 8/15/2017    | 4500        | Continue count| >2000 (2) |
  | 3344   | 9/15/2017    | 6000        | Continue count| >2000 (3) |
  | 3344   | 10/15/2017   | 7000        | Stop count| >3 in a row   |
  | 3344   | 11/15/2017   | 8000        | Stop count| >3 in a row   |
  |        |              |             |                           |
  | 6678   | 8/15/2017    | 3000        | Count| >2000 (1)          |
  | 6678   | 9/15/2017    | 4000        | Continue count| >2000 (2) |
  | 6678   | 10/15/2017   | 5000        | Continue count| >2000 (3) |
  ```

I also have a loc_id dimension that includes the location open date.

```
| loc_id | loc_open_dt |
|--------|-------------|
| 1234   | 2002-05-01  |
| 9987   | 2006-10-22  |
| 5544   | 2015-03-04  |
| 2223   | 2017-05-05  |
| 3344   | 2017-07-05  |
| 6678   | 2017-08-01  |
```

Comment: What if after a longer run of +2000 amounts, they are again lower, and a new series of +2000 of 3 emerges. Should that location be listed again then? What if a location has exactly 3 consecutive +2000 amounts, but then again lower amounts, should it continue to be listed in those lower months?

Comment: 1st question: YES - If an ID dips below 2000 after a run of 3 with >2000, that ID should be listed again. 2nd question: YES - if an ID has exactly 3 with >2000, then in month 4 dips to <2000, it should not be returned again UNTIL it has another consecutive run of 3 months. Thanks!

Comment: use group by with aggregate expresions: `https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-AGGREGATES`

Comment: @JustMe that URL does not exist

Comment: @psrpsrpsr https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-AGGREGATES

Comment: The case of 6678 is strange: the invoices are for 2017, 2016 and 2015, in that order, and they count as a hit? Isn't that a mistake in your data?

Comment: @trincot yes that is a mistake! Sorry about that - I just edited the example data and Rextester link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is query that checks that:

- the months with >=2000 amounts are consecutive, and
- the month preceding the listing date is the last one of those, and
- if there is an amount for the month preceding those three, it is below 2000

Query:

```
select distinct loc_id
from   (
        select loc_id, 
               first_value(invoice_amt) over win                            first_amt,
               floor((list_date - first_value(invoice_date) over win)/30)+1 month_count,
               list_date - last_value(invoice_date) over win < 30           has_last_month,
               count(case when invoice_amt >= 2000 then 1 end) over win     large_amt_count
        from   invoices,
               (select date '2017-10-01' /* current_date */ list_date) ref 
        where  invoice_date between (list_date - 120) and list_date
        window win as (partition by loc_id order by invoice_date)
       ) base
where  month_count = 3 + (first_amt < 2000)::int
   and large_amt_count = 3
   and has_last_month;
```

See it run on [rextester](http://rextester.com/XACL96205)

Change the literal date in the middle of the query to your actual reporting date (or `current_date`).

Answer (score 1):

In PostgreSQL you can use a window function. You need to build the windows by aggregating your data by `loc_id` and then check that 3 conscutive rows have an `invoice_amt` greater than the target value. The trick is done by using the `lag()` function that, applied over a window, let you grab data from the *previous* rows. The code is much simpler than the explanation:

```
SELECT DISTINCT loc_id FROM (
  SELECT *, 
         invoice_amt > 10000 AS a, 
         lag(invoice_amt, 1) OVER w > 10000 AS b,
         lag(invoice_amt, 2) OVER w > 10000 AS c,
         extract('month' from invoice_date::date) AS m1, 
         extract('month' from (lag(invoice_date, 1) OVER w)::date + '1 month'::interval) AS m2, 
         extract('month' from (lag(invoice_date, 2) OVER w)::date + '2 month'::interval) AS m3
    FROM invoices 
  WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY loc_id ORDER BY invoice_date)
) X 
 WHERE a AND b AND c AND m2 = m1 AND m3 = m1
```

Note also the check on *consecutive* months. We just add 1 or 2 months to the `lag()`ged date and then check that the month is same for the three consecutive rows (as asked in the comments).

If you want to better understand how that works just run only the inner `SELECT` and look at the results.

Comment: How can I include functionality/logic into this such that it returns ONLY IDs that have had EXACTLY three consecutive months in relation to the report run date? For example, ID 1234 in my sample data would be a false positive using this method, because it's third consecutive month was in Aug. 2002.

Comment: You can extract the month from `invoice_date` using another `lag()` call. Right now I am away from computer, I'll update the answer later.

Comment: @psrpsrpst I have added the check about consecutive months.